# Android: int which in DialogInterface.OnClickListener() is -1

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I don't understand why this is happening. I have the following code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivityNew.this);

builder.setTitle("Title");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.example_arrays, 1, null);              
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivityNew.this, "which: " + which, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
builder.show();
```

For some strange reason, the int which, keeps giving me -1. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the doc :

```
Parameters
dialog  The dialog that received the click.
which   The button that was clicked (e.g. BUTTON1) or the position of the item clicked.
```

---

BUTTON_POSITIVE :

```
public static final int BUTTON_POSITIVE

Added in API level 3
The identifier for the positive button.

Constant Value: -1 (0xffffffff)
```

So that's not strange but totally normal. You get -1 each time because you clicked on the `positiveButton` of your dialog :)

Comment: Ooh, okay, thanks. Then I misunderstood it, I thought is was returning position of the selected item in the list the dialog displays, but I bet I need something else for that.

Comment: You'd assume that the `which` would be the id, as in `((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).getId()` (in my case at least). But, it seems that `DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE` is what is being passed instead.